# How return all elements array in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller:

```
def grafico_gantt 
    @mapa = Hash.new
    @mapa[:tasks] = []
    @projeto.atividades.each do |a|
        @mapa[:tasks] << {
           id:a.id,
           descricao:a.descricao,
           status:a.status,
           data_inicial:a.data_inicial.to_datetime.to_i*1000,
           tempo_gasto:a.tempo_gasto.to_i,
           data_final:a.data_final.to_datetime.to_i*1000
        }
    end
end
```

And a .js.erb

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        "use strict";
        $(".gantt").gantt({
            source: [{
                name: '<%= raw @mapa[:tasks][0][:descricao] %>',
                desc: '<%= raw @mapa[:tasks][0][:status] %>'+"% concluído",
                values: [{
                    from: "/Date(<%= raw @mapa[:tasks][0][:data_inicial] %>)/",
                    to: "/Date(<%= raw @mapa[:tasks][0][:data_final] %>)/",
                    label:"<%= raw @mapa[:tasks][0][:descricao] %>", 
                    customClass: "ganttRed"
                }]
            }],
        scale: "days",
        minScale: "days",
        maxScale:"months",
        navigate: "scroll",
        waitText: "Aguarde...",
    });
</script>
```

I have 3 values in arrays, but, how can see, i just take 1, @mapa[:tasks][0][:descricao]
How a can take all values? Because @mapa[:tasks][:descricao] don't work :/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd write the controller more like this (untested) code:

```
def grafico_gantt 
  @mapa = {}
  @mapa[:tasks] = @projeto.atividades.map { |a|
    {
      id: a.id,
      descricao: a.descricao,
      status: a.status,
      data_inicial: a.data_inicial.to_datetime.to_i * 1000,
      tempo_gasto: a.tempo_gasto.to_i,
      data_final: a.data_final.to_datetime.to_i * 1000
    }
  }
end
```

To access all the `descricao` elements of the returned array, use a [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) or [`collect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect) to transform the array into just the parts you want:

```
@mapa[:tasks].collect { |e| e[:descricao] }
```

`map` and `collect` are synonymous. Though they are aliased, sometimes it makes more sense syntactically to use `collect`, and sometimes `map` makes more sense.

In the rewrite of the code above, it's a little confusing why you create a hash of hashes. A single element hash of hashes is a bit... confusing... inelegant, but maybe you're not showing us everything.

If nothing else is added to the hash, I'd recommend simplifying it to:

```
def grafico_gantt 
  @mapa = @projeto.atividades.map { |a|
    {
      id: a.id,
      descricao: a.descricao,
      status: a.status,
      data_inicial: a.data_inicial.to_datetime.to_i * 1000,
      tempo_gasto: a.tempo_gasto.to_i,
      data_final: a.data_final.to_datetime.to_i * 1000
    }
  }
end
```

Which will return an array of hashes and simplify your accesses into it by removing the need to find the `[:tasks]` element:

```
@mapa.collect { |e| e[:descricao] }
```

Comment: Thanks for help!!! oddly dont work with me... i think that must continue with my old code :l
but, thanks so much *-*

Answer (score 0):

how is this :

```
@mapa[:tasks].each{|e| puts e[:descricao] }
```

or

```
@mapa[:tasks].map{|e| e[:descricao] }
```